# After login page landing page(Home page) is not loading while using Appium but it loads in mobile

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I am testing an android application on real device and I am not able to navigate to certain pages when Appium run, But the app works in mobile without Appium

I have followed following Steps:

(In other mobiles) Open the app to the main homepage - Not Loading and showing alert (There was an unexpected error in request processing. please try again) loads the DOM
Navigate to login page-  loads the page fine and am able to inspect the elements.
Enter credential and click on submit button and proceed to landing screen - Not loading hpme page

But when I tap on the phone the home screen is loaded on without Appium connected.

I don't know why the landing page is not loading.
while running the test through TestNG -it cannot find the particular element(s), acting similarly to what inspector is doing.

Used Appium version: 2.2.0

I want load home page [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm89S.png)